# Uno application run on MacOS - problem with elements accessibility

Tags: macos, uno-platform, uno

I have the MacOS application developped using UNO Platform whitch i would like to test using appium.  Application was is fully fucntional for manual usage.

Then i encountered an issue with accessibility inspector that default MacOS window buttons like "close application", "maximalize", and "minimalize" can be accessed wia UIElementInspector but almost **all of the application connetnt cannot be accessed(they are not listed at all) as a children of the main window. Only images are accessible but none of the buttons neither texts.**

I checked other applications like calculator, visual studio etc and hadn't simillar problems - every element was listed, so in my opinion problem is not coming form system but the application or uno platrorm  itself. Remark - on windows this application hadn't such inssue with contetnt acessibility.

Also found example application developed in uno platform and this applicacion  also does not share the elements in inspector.

> https://github.com/unoplatform/Uno.Ch9

Have anyone had faced similar problem and was able to solve it?

Comment: This definitely seems like a bug on macOS implementation of Uno Platform. Can you please report it as an issue on GitHub? We will prioritize it accordingly. https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/

Comment: Thank You for response. I submitted the issue under the following link:
https://github.com/unoplatform/uno/issues/8047